# How dangerous is reflected request query strings?

Tags: authentication, xss

I have discovered a possible security flaw in a login for a site that many people rely on. I won't say the site but in the URL there is something similar to

```
/Success?message=Success+please+wait+a+bit+for+results

/Failure?message=Failure+Please+try+again
```

I know all about XSS, and you can't get JavaScript to be embedded even with trickery, but it still prints what you put in the message query.

I think this could possibly be used in social engineering attacks

How dangerous is this? (it CAN be hot-linked)

Comment: Some sites opt for that, others display it within <body> tag, but as long as the message does not disclose some sensitive info nothing is wrong with that. All what you can do is to try manipulating the variable `message` with the common techniques. And do not ask more because questions about how to break a system are not allowed

Comment: The message query allows you to input anything and it will display, so is it not a security flaw that it could be linked and show someone text that you want whilst making it look like its coming from the site?

Answer (score 1):

You can host all the phishing emails there. For example:

> We have detected suspicious behavior on your account. All furthur login requests will be denied. Please use the alternative login form at http://example.com/ to do a secure log in and unlock your account.

Comment: Yes, this is about along the lines of what i was thinking. The web master has not responded to my email and it has been a couple weeks. Many people rely on this website, what should I do?

Comment: @KevinFroman I don't usually find security holes on other site, so I'm not sure what to do exactly. Maybe that's another question.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your feedback. Its a physical place so I'll try to find someone to talk to in person about it when I can.

Comment: I would assume that you probably can't inject clickable links though. If XSS is not possible, `'">` are probably encoded. Phishing might still be possible, but that makes it a bit more difficult (eg "For security purposes this link is not clickable. Please copy-paste it: [link to phishing site]").